# How to remove the part of text in one column that matches the value of another column?

Tags: powerbi, m

I have a table with a column of email addresses and another column of unique IDs. For some reason, some of the values in the email address are prefixed with the unique IDs so I need to do some cleanup of the email address column by removing the unique ID prefix from the email address column. The length of the unique ID can vary, so it's not as straight forward as the only method I know of simply removing the first x amount of characters:

| email | unique ID |
| --- | --- |
| george@hotmail.com | 79fsdfv8v2657f842356j0 |
| 784ret3956w35497er834r62mary@hotmail.com | 784ret3956w35497er834r62 |
| 34gfng6w5h6pauly@outlook.com | 34gfng6w5h6 |

Resulting column:

```
george@hotmail.com
mary@hotmail.com
pauly@outlook.com
```

The solution has to be in m code, not DAX. Any ideas?

Comment: change the tags please according to the last part of your question...

Comment: you didnt like my answer 

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found this answer and their solution solved my problem:

> https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Dynamically-remove-string-from-one-column-if-string-is-contained/td-p/1809532

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    CLEAN = Table.ReplaceValue(Table.TransformColumns(Table.AddColumn(Source, "All ICD-10 Replaced", 
    each if Text.Contains([#"All ICD-10"], [#"ICD-10"])
        then Text.Replace([#"All ICD-10"], [#"ICD-10"], "")
        else [#"All ICD-10"]),
    {{"All ICD-10 Replaced", Text.Trim, type text}}),
     "  "," ",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"All ICD-10 Replaced"})
in
    CLEAN
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do it on the power query side...

```
        let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("dYzNCgIhEIBfJea8RKgz6m3fQzxIqVtpE667y759EARBdP5+nIMcueU4TtxruJbjmesBBtA2zZe0mlUQ6mSUkEi3E/jBgTaqxS4t0iZRWR2bkaqRqKHtP5s/7nskVU6PTBtO9AxL2UdeemG+f+IvDt6/AA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"email " = _t, #"unique ID" = _t]),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(Source, "email ", "email  - Original"),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Duplicated Column",each [unique ID],"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"email "}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Replaced Value",{{"email ", "Result"}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"unique ID", "email  - Original", "Result"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

[sample file as solved above...](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M3MJ1K_-q787odX2wg9OCf16D0x-svMc/view?usp=sharing)

[image: new result]

[image: first]

[image: result]

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. the resulting column is identical to the original email column

Comment: @Sweepsterit just copy my code and see yourself, it is working...

Comment: @Sweepster you can duplicate the email column and work on it if you want the result on a separate column...

Comment: No, what happens is that it doesn't remove the unique ID from the email address. See my found solution.

Comment: @Sweepster you havent even tried for sure... [check the sample file and see it is working perfectly](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M3MJ1K_-q787odX2wg9OCf16D0x-svMc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The sample file and solution was fine. If it did not work, it was used wrong

Comment: When you expand the sample, it fails to do the job in other scenarios.

Comment: @Sweepster if you add the other scenarios into your sample data, we can find out why it is not working properly...